# SQL not updating a previous entry

Tags: python, sqlite, api

Still new to API's so please excuse any novice mistakes
This is where I receive the input from another port and then it gets sent to PUT method

```
@app.route('/PUT', methods=['POST'])
def PUT_link():
    first_name = request.form['fname']
    last_name = request.form['lname']
    number = request.form['number']
    Methods.PUT(first_name, last_name, number)
    return 'success'
```

This is the method that should update the number but it doesn't.

```
@classmethod
    def PUT(cls, first_name, last_name, number):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
        cur = connection.cursor()
        query = "UPDATE contacts SET number=? WHERE firstname=? AND lastname=?"
        cur.execute(query, (first_name, last_name, number))
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
        return 'Contact number updated'
```

Comment: Is `number` an integer? If so, you would have to convert it to an int like this: `number = int(request.form['number'])` Otherwise, if you try to write a string the query will fail.

Comment: I tried your solution but no dice. In the other functions it posts the number into the database without int(). The database only accepts int when it takes in a number.

Comment: I think the order of values in the tuple are wrong. Try this: `cur.execute(query, (number, first_name, last_name))`